# how to start rabbitmq server on port 8080

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am unable to start rabbitmq on 8080. How can I do it? I am also unable to find rabbitmq.conf on ubuntu.  Please kindly help me regarding this.

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost("localhost");
factory.setPort(8080);
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
String message = "Hello World!";
channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");
channel.close();
connection.close();
```

And i get these errors when I run it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.createFrameHandler(ConnectionFactory.java:445)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:504)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:533)
    at javaapplication3.rabbitchat.main(rabbitchat.java:26)
```

Comment: Did u started rabbitmq-server on localhost with default 5672 port ?

Answer (score 4):

You can start rabbitmq service on port 8080 by using following command:

```
:~$ RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT=8080 rabbitmq-server
```

By default, first instance has node name "rabbit" if not configured at start time. If you want to start rabbitmq service with different `NODENAME` or multiple instances of rabbitmq server for clustering, you will need to change the `NODENAME` as well as `NODE_PORT` for each instance you start like:

```
:~$ RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT=<PORT> RABBITMQ_NODENAME=<UNIQUE_NODENAME> rabbitmq-server
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that no other process is running on port 8080? This is a very popular port. (Oracle uses it, a lot of application servers, etc)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still interested, I get the "Connection refused" error, *only* when I use the commend "setPort". When I comment that out, it works!

I also have code that outputs the port #, and it says it's set to 8080 eventhough I took setPort(8080) out... very strange...

Answer (score 0):

A rabbitmq.conf file does not generally come with the apt version of Rabbitmq, however Rabbit will always look for that file on startup, so you could create it manually. http://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#configuration-file

As Kurt Du Bois said, make sure nothing else is running on that port, running `netstat -anlp | grep 8080` should give you that information.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle will run on 8080 port. so if u need to run rabbitmq on 8080, stop Oracle service.